# How to cache a list resulted from database in a Rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord, redis

How do I cache a list resulted from database in a Rails query?

```
@total_untagged = Rails.cache.fetch("tags_controller/untagged/@total_untagged", expires_in: 1.hour) do
        InventoryApi::BaseEntity\
          .joins(@object_type.to_sym)
          .includes(:base_entities_tags)
          .where({ base_entities_tags: { base_entity_id: nil }})
          .size.to_int
        end
```

This code is loading the InventoryApi::BaseEntity model and saving it in a cache with a key value of:

```
tags_controller/untagged/@total_untagged
```

The cached result is an Instance, lazily-loaded from the database, not eager-loaded as the class with the field values.

Once it's lazily-loaded, when the cache is read it needs to read the database again, in fact, I gain nothing caching.

How can I cache the final result, not the database relation?

Answer (score 0):

Once its saved in the cache, it does not need to read the database again until the cache is invalidated. In case you are using this locally, here is something you should have in mind. This is from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html.

> To play around with caching locally you'll want to enable caching in your local environment by setting config.action_controller.perform_caching to true in relevant config/environments/*.rb.
>
> Changing the value of config.action_controller.perform_caching will only have an effect on the caching provided by the Action Controller component. For instance, it will not impact low-level caching.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my questions is not about it. I know once saved in cache there is no need to go back in database, and is that what I want, but what is beeing cached is not the data itself, but the database loader, so, once read from cache, data need to be loaded from database again, and is exaclty that what I want to avoid.

I've already changed config files, cache is beeing saved and used, but as I said, what is beeing saved is not what I need.

Comment: If this is the case, then why dont you cache the exact result received from the database, by fetching it instead of the relation.

Comment: I am asking how to do that. This is my question.